# Controlling a widget's property in Screen Manager (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I'm new to kivy. I'm trying to make an application consisting of multiple screens. Each screen consists of a layout and some widgets. I want to get a usual functionality from my buttons, not just switching screens.
For example I want to change a label's text with a button's on_press method.
How can i do that?
here is my .py code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class ScreenOne(Screen):
   flo = ObjectProperty(None)
   def b1p(self, instance):
        global psss
        psss = "1"+psss
        print("okok")

        print(Manager.__dict__)
        print(root.ids.screen_one.ids.label1.text)
##        print(ScreenOne.flo.button1.text)
        instance.text = "hk"
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass
global psss
psss= ""
class Manager(ScreenManager):
##    font_sizte = NumericProperty(20)

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_three = ObjectProperty(None)
    def b1p(self):
        global psss
        psss = "1"+psss
        print("okok")
##        self.button1.text = "hi" 


class ScreensApp(App):
    font_size_pssscreen = 30
    shx_pssscreen = 0.1
    shy_pssscreen = 0.15
    def build (self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

and the .kv code:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
<ScreenOne>:
    flo : flo
    FloatLayout:
        id:flo

        label1 : label1
        button1:button1
        button2:button2
        button3:button3
        button4:button4
        button5:button5
        button6:button6
        button7:button7
        button8:button8
        button9:button9
        Button:
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            id:button1
            pos_hint:{"x":.3,"top":.75}
            back_color:.1,.3,.6,1
            text:"1"
            on_press:root.b1p(root.manager)
            #on_press: self.text +=root


        Button:
            id:button2
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.45,"top":.75}
            text:"2"
            on_press:button2.text:"jio"
        Button:
            id:button3
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"top":.75}
            text:"3"
        Button:
            id:button4
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"top":.55}
            text:"4"
            on_press:root.manager.current = 'screen2'
        Button:
            id:button5
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.45,"top":.55}
            text:"5"
        Button:
            id:button6
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"top":.55}
            text:"6"
        Button:
            id:button7
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"top":.35}
            text:"7"
        Button:
            id:button8
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.45,"top":.35}
            text:"8"
        Button:
            id:button9
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"top":.35}
            text:"9"    
        Label:
            id:label1
            font_size :app.font_size_pssscreen
            color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
            size_hint:app.shx_pssscreen,app.shy_pssscreen
            pos_hint:{"x":0.0,"top":1.3}
            text:"w"







<ScreenTwo>:
    Button:
        text:"hi"
<ScreenThree>:
    Button:
        text:"hi"
<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two:screen_two
    screen_three:screen_three

    ScreenOne:
        id:screen_one
        name: 'screen1'
        manager:screen_manager
    ScreenTwo:
        id:screen_two
        name: 'screen2'
        manager:screen_manager
    ScreenThree:    
        id:screen_three
        name: 'screen3'
        manager:screen_manager
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `b1p()` method of `ScreenOne`, just add a call to change the text:

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
   flo = ObjectProperty(None)

   def b1p(self, instance):
        global psss
        psss = "1"+psss
        print("okok")

        # next line changes the text of label1
        self.ids.label1.text = 'Changed Text'
```